# Python, function for an arithmetic sequence

Tags: python, function

The sequence goes like this: 1+ 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4!...... 1/n!
It's basically 1 divided by some factorial until it reaches n!

I have figured out how to calculate the factorial, example: 5!
That code looks like this:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n
    return n * factorial(n-1)
```

I've tried to google a solution but can't seem to find any :(

How would I code this?

Comment: If you know the value of `1/n!` how would you calculate `1/(n+1)!`?

Comment: I'd recommend using the `factorial()` function from the `math` package, which contains some optimizations that make it much faster than any code written in pure python

Comment: So, your assignment is really "google for a solution"? Shouldn't that rather be "learn how to do it"?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `math` module:

```py
import math

def seq(t=100):
    out = 0
    for i in range(1,t):
        out += 1 / math.factorial(i)
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `factorial` function (yours or `math.factorial`), the rest is almost plain English ;)

```
sum(1/factorial(i+1) for i in range(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, clearly you can return the inverse factorial by just returning the inverse:

```
    return factorial(n-1) / n
```

But for a sequence, that's wasteful.  Look at your sequence:

```
    1   1 1   1 1 1
1 + - + - - + - - - + ...
    2   2 3   2 3 4
```

Notice that each step is just the previous step times the new value.  It would be better not to have "factorial" as a separate function:

```
def sequence(steps):
    term = 1
    sumx = 1
    for i in range(2,steps):
        term /= i
        sumx += term
    return sumx
```

Comment: No, I don't.  I preseed `term` and `sumx` with the 1 already built-in.  If I had set `sumx` to 0, then I would have started at 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a second function using recursion and the existing factorial function:

```
def compute_sequence(n):
    num = 1/factorial(n)
    if n == 1:
        return num
    return num + compute_sequence(n-1)
```

Then you would just call:
`compute_sequence(n)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

def sequence(p):
    sum = 0
    while(p>0):
        fact = factorial(p)
        sum += (1/fact)
        p -=1
    return sum

print(sequence(3))
```

output:

```
1.6666666666666665
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).